# Can I clear users out of my AD without harming any entries in a Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

Apologies for the basic question; we're having a spring clean of the office Active Directory and plan to remove a large number of legacy users. Saying good-bye to their email is not a problem, but we have an on-premise Dynamics CRM we occasionally refer to. My question is, will there be any implications for that if I delete a user who might have entered a case?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct link between CRM on-premise 2011 & Active Directory to pull all users overnight & sync. When you create a new user in CRM by giving domain name, it will verify in AD & pull the details to store in CRM. This will happen on tab out.

So when you delete/disable an AD user it won't flow down in Dynamics. But you have to disable them manually (no delete option available). Before doing that make sure to read these [best practices](https://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2012/08/28/disable-user-accounts-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011/).

> **Best Practices**
>
> Make sure to Re-assign any associated records/activities to another
>   User or Team before disabling User. If you don’t Re-assign the records
>   they will still be available, but they will still be assigned to the
>   disabled user.
>
> It is very important to ensure that there are no Workflows owned by
>   the User to be disabled. All Published Workflows need to be owned by
>   an administrative account, not an employee’s account.
>
> There are situations where a User’s account only needs to be disabled
>   for a short period of time, so records don’t necessarily need to be
>   Re-assigned. (Example: the User went on vacation for a month). Take
>   into consideration the User’s privileges for those records. If only
>   the User can modify that record, then no one will be able to modify
>   the record, if the owner is disabled.

Read this [community thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/170724) as well.

Comment: @Mocl happy to help.